# Android studio 4.0.1 consuming too much memory on every execution

Tags: android, android-studio

On every execution, Android studio is occupying 1GB RAM. Leads to system hang on every 5 executions.

Comment: on every execution, 1 GB space is occupying & having 8 GB RAM

Comment: every time of execution it is occupying 1GB space on 5 executions it is reaching to 5GB, I am using Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, from **Help** menu select **Edit Custom VM Options...** , then write **-Xmx512m** in a new line in there.

[image]

Then restart Android Studio. That worked for me.